# Different memcached instance per user, with authentication

Tags: memcached

I am writing a script which will allow each and every cPanel user to run an instance of memcached on their own.

The script at  this point is starting the daemon for every user on a different port. However I would like to set a username and a password for the memcached instance so the users can connect to their own memcached instance.

Could someone give a hint how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Memcached has been patched to allow for SASL-based authentication. You can find more information on this here: https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol.

A brief HOWTO is here: https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto.

Comment: Hello, 

The goal here is to enable the memcached service for most of the opensource applications such as Joomla, Wordpress etc. Not all of these applications (or should I say none) have the option for such authentication. 

Most of them are connecting to the memcached daemon only on certain port with no other additional options. Since the cached contents for all of the users are stored in the memory I want to disallow the users for accessing the other users cached contents. 

How this can be alternatively achieved if I am not using the SASL based authentication. 

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to have authentication enforced without having to make sure that the application is also aware of the authentication. That's pretty much impossible.

Comment: I have searched over the web for an alternative solution, however I have been unable to find such. Indeed the SASL based authentication remain the only aproach for an user to authenticate in front of memcached. Thank you for you answer!